# Is it UB on derefencing pointer or not?

Tags: c++

I have some [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ABnjxUQP09lGl8Ms) and  i can't understand is there a UB on dereferencing pointer or not. It works OK, but i have have doubts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class T>
struct NullRef
{
    static T& null(void)
    {
        static T* p(nullptr);
        return *p;
    }
    static bool isNull(const T& t)
    {
        return &t == &null();
    }
};

bool foo(const int& r = NullRef<int>::null()) {
    return NullRef<int>::isNull(r);
}

int main()
{    
    std::cout << "isNull = "<<foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As per the answer in the duplicate: yes, dereferencing that pointer to obtain the l-value returned by the function `null` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Clang says: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int'

Comment: Yes, it is undefined behavior to dereference a nullptr.  "(Undefined behavior) works OK" may appear to work okay.  Or it may crash.  Or it may do something weird.  Or it may work okay on your machine, and crash or do something weird on someone else's machine.  _Undefined behavior_ is fickle that way.